# Highchart Array From Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, highcharts

I have array From ajax Responses Look Like This

```
[
    {
        "name":"online",
        "data":["34","155","12"]
    },
        {"name":"ofline",
        "data":["34","155","12"]
    }
]
```

ANd I want to add to Highchart Using ajax look this , but thats Wrong

```
$.getJSON("MYURL", {"cab":cab,"spv":spv,"sls":sls,"rg":rg}, function(data){
            options.series = data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

Comment: My Complete Code https://pastebin.com/9bRbFWLN

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `yAxis` is missing.
Besides, the data must be under following format:

```
{
    name: 'online',
    marker: {
        symbol: 'diamond'
    },
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 155, 12, 0, 0, 0]
},{
    name: 'offline',
    marker: {
        symbol: 'square'
    },
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 291, 182, 37, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

For more details, view [this](https://codepen.io/nguyn-c-ng-s-ng/pen/gOrGqMW)

Comment: i think i can using Push series or looping in each in My getJson ?

Comment: Ohh Sure @Sangnc Now I have data Lokk Like This 
[
 {
  "name":"online",
  "data":["34","155","12"]
 },
  {"name":"ofline",
  "data":["34","155","12"]
 }
]

Comment: Yes, you can use loops to change your `series`.

Comment: I have update my codepen:
`while (chart.series.length) {
  chart.series[0].remove();
}
var index = 0;
for(var index = 0; index <= data.length; index++){
  chart.addSeries(data[index], false);
}
chart.redraw();`

Answer (score 0):

The data array must be an array of numbers, not the strings - you need to change that on the backend site while rendering data or parse the data to an array of numbers just before to insert to the chart.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/twkxezpy/

```
let dataFromDataBase = [{
    "name": "online",
    "data": [34, 155, 12]
  },
  {
    "name": "ofline",
    "data": [34, 155, 12]
  }
];
```